# How to set row spacing in Angular Material's Grid?

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I can't seem to find a way to set the spacing between rows for Angular Material's [Grid List](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview). I've tried gutter size, but it only crops up my tile content. I can't find a plunker or a fiddler for Angular Material, and I know the question is a little bit too specific, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can set row spacing by `gutterSize` property like this

```
<mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="2:1" [gutterSize]="'10px'">
  <mat-grid-tile>1</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>2</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>3</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>4</mat-grid-tile>
</mat-grid-list>
```

[**stackblitz demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bcpnxh)

Comment: This worked but I do not understand why. How does the gutterSize come into play?

Comment: @GregHarner, it's a property of **MatGridList**, you can check it [here](https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/api#MatGridList)

Answer (score -1):

I used the same code to solve the problem, but my first line looked like this:

I basically did not need to use the brackets and extra single quotes.